# UIViewController wrong size after UISearchController

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have an `UIViewController` and in this I show `UISearchController` in the `navigationbar`. In `ios11 . +` this will increase the `navigationbar` height. That's okay for me. So the user click on my button to show the `searchbar`, and I show it. If the user click on the cancel button I remove the `searchbar`.
The problem is occuring when the user click on the button to show the `searchbar` and after this, the user wants to go another `UIViewController`. I load the another `UIViewController` and I got a black bar between the `navigationbar` and the content.
I logged out the height of the view:

These are the ideal sizes:

> viewDidLoad - NavBar SIZE: 44.000000
>
> viewDidLoad - view SIZE: 667.000000
>
> viewWillAppear - NavBar SIZE: 44.000000
>
> viewWillAppear - view SIZE: 603.000000

And these are the wrong sizes:

> viewDidLoad - NavBar SIZE: 44.000000
>
> viewDidLoad - view SIZE: 667.000000
>
> viewWillAppear - NavBar SIZE: 44.000000
>
> viewWillAppear - view SIZE: 551.000000

You can see that the height of the view in the `viewWillAppear` method is smaller than expected. Why?
I tried to force update the layout:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ios11 + Navigation bar + Searchbar always creates problems since it launched

I have faced similar issue when View Size is different when I push View controller from View controller which has search bar. and shows **BLACK BAR** next to the Navigation bar

There are number of solution available like fixed height of Search bar but it behaves unexpectedly

For that I found solution to create subclass of UIView

```
class SearchBarContainerView: UIView {

    let searchBar: UISearchBar

    init(customSearchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar = customSearchBar
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        addSubview(searchBar)
    }

    override convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.init(customSearchBar: UISearchBar())
        self.frame = frame
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        searchBar.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

And then use this as Title View

```
    // Search bar
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = nil

    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    let searchBarContainer = SearchBarContainerView(customSearchBar: self.searchController.searchBar)

    searchBarContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 44)
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBarContainer
```

Hope it is helpful to you in your case

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!

Comment: @just Good luck :)

Comment: So, thank you very much, this is working fine, but this solution doesn't use the ios11 "feature" that the searchbar will be under the title.. Now its working, but I need to refactor a bit my navigationbar to hide other icons.

Comment: I have one more problem with this solution... How can I set transparent background to this?

Comment: No, because clear color result was black background... I set the navigationbar color to the searchbar too

Comment: @just  Ok Great !!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this issue does not appear if the `UISearchController` is not focused when you push the new `UIViewController`.

Just make sure that before pushing the new ViewController you will do
`self.navigationItem.searchController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`.

If you have to have the "focus" on the search controller after going back, create the focus from code in `viewWillAppear` once again.